# How to pass the data when back button is pressed in android to previous activity?

Tags: android

```
  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case REQUEST_CODE_GETMESSAGE:
                if(requestCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
                {
                    String message=data.getStringExtra("data");

                    Log.i("MyApp","Result message is:" +message);
                }else
                {

                    Log.i("MyApp","Activity Cancelled");
                }

        }
    }
Else part is working
```

Comment: With checking _resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK_

Answer (score 2):

Activity1 should start Activity2 with `startActivityForResult()`.

Activity2 should use `setResult()` to send data back to Activity1.

In Activity2,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("MyData", data);
    setResult(resultcode, intent);
}
```

In Activity1,

```
onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String myStr=data.getStringExtra("MyData");
            mTextView.setText(myStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `setResult(resultcode, intent);` to  `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);`

Comment: ya changed but still not getting the data onbackpressed :-(

Answer (score 0):

Its 2022!
This answer is up to date based on kotlin.

**Step 1: On 1st Activity**

```
lateinit var activityResultLaunch: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        activityResultLaunch = registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result ->
            when(result.resultCode){
                101 -> {
                    val tab_name = result.data?.getStringExtra("TAB_NAME")
                }
                else -> {}
            }
        }

       

       // this is the trick and must be open 2nd activity like this 
       button.onClicked {
        activityResultLaunch.launch(Intent(this, 2ndActivity::class.java))
       }


  }


override fun onDestroy() {
        activityResultLaunch.unregister()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

**Step 2: On 2nd Activity**

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val intent = Intent()
            intent.putExtra("TAB_NAME", "Home")
            setResult(101, intent)
            finish()
    }
```

Happy coding :)